# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'My_database_Name.posts' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to generate CRUD for User table.
when I tried to validate request data i got Error in validation section.

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02) SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
>   table or view not found: 1146 Table 'My_database_Name.posts' doesn't
>   exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where
>   `usr_email` = testingadmin@test.com) Previous exceptions
>
> ```
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'My_database_name.posts' doesn't exist (42S02)
> ```

If I remove validation part the code work fine for me.

Thanks.

My Controller's  update() code is

> ```
> public function update( Request $request ,$user)
>     {
>         $request->validate([
>             'usr_first_name' => 'required',
>             'usr_last_name' => 'required',
>             'usr_email' => 'required|unique:posts',
>             'usr_phone' => 'required|numeric|min:2|max:5',
>             'usr_address' => 'required',
>             'usr_type' => 'required',
>         ]);
>         $user = User::where('id', $user)->first();
>
>         $user->firstname    = $request->input('usr_first_name');
>         $user->lastname     = $request->input('usr_last_name');
>         $user->email        = $request->input('usr_email');
>         $user->phone        = $request->input('usr_phone');
>         $user->address      = $request->input('usr_address');
>         $user->type         = $request->input('usr_type');
>         $user->save();
>
>         return redirect()->action('UserController@index');
>     }
> ```

Comment: Could you paste your code ?

Comment: From the error message you pasted I think it's something related to unique rule validation

Comment: @Fouèd Moussi thanks for your  suggestion  i got the error in code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can guess that your `usr_email` attribute do not belongs to posts table, it belongs to users table (`$user->email = $request->input('usr_email');`)

**Fix**

```
//...
'usr_email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
//..
```